# Conversion of EPS to PDF or Tiff does not maintain transparency

Tags: pdf, tiff, ghostscript, eps

I am trying to convert eps file to pdf file or tiff file using ghostscript but having issues keeping it transparent. When I convert it to png, transparency is maintained but I need to have pdf or tiff for printing purpose.
To convert it to PDF, I am using below Arguments:

For PDF

> -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=C:\temp\test.pdf
>   C:\temp\test.eps;

For Tiff

> -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -r300 -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=C:\temp\test.tiff  
>  C:\temp\test.eps;

is there something I am missing or is it not possible to maintain transparancy?

Answer (score 0):

EPS cannot contain transparency, its not part of the standard, so I don't really see how it can fail to 'maintain' it....

Comment: My knowledge of Image file types is very limited. When I convert it to PNG, it creates a transparent background but when I convert to PDF or Tiff, it creates them with white background. I want to avoid the white background.

Comment: I'm not at all clear on why you think it has a white background in PDF (which is not an image file type), the background in a PDF is unmarked which defaults to white, but that's not the same thing. As for TIFF, there is no support in GS for making the unmarked areas transparent. If you want to do that then use PNG, its the only image format for which Ghostscript sets the unmarked area to transparent. Bear in mind that the PostScript standard requires that the page be erased (to white by default) before printing, so this is rather expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks KenS for your comments. I will discuss this with the team to whom I have to deliver. May be this is what they want ..

Comment: You can convert to PNG and then to TIFF and maintain transparency.  Transparency doesn't mean much in PDF.  In later versions of the spec, it has to do with how multiple layers on a page are blended before being rendered onto the background medium, which is assumed to be opaque.