# Convert PDF to Tiff With CMYK and Transparency

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, tiff, cmyk

I’m attempting to convert from PDF to TIFF and maintain both the CMYK color space and the transparent areas in the PDF. There are many posts out there say “just use PNG” but for my application the CMYK color space is a must and PNG doesn’t support CMYK. I started working on this using Imagemagick (IM) and had limited success but had better results so far using Ghostscript directly (which is what IM uses under the hood anyway). The problem that continually occurs is that the transparent areas from the PDF are filled in with white.

Context:
 Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (AWS), Ghostscript 9.23, ImageMagick 7.0.7-36

I created a test PDF that has a transparent background and overlapping blocks of solid and semi-transparent colors:
[trans-test.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghwr9h0e4i6kiso/trans-test.pdf?dl=0)

I’ve verified that the PDF has the correct transparent areas. If I use PNG (and thus the RGB colorspace) I get the resulting image which has the matching transparent areas as the PDF but, alas, the wrong colorspace:
[output.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6m7p98h23cxm53/output.png?dl=0)

> (remember: web browsers will show it with a white background but it’s really transparent)

For conversions I’ve tried variations of the following commands (simplified for posting):

Imagemagick: 
`convert -depth 8 -colorspace CMYK trans-test.pdf output.tif`

Ghostscript: 
`gs -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -sOutputFile=output_gs.tif -r144 trans-test.pdf`

In IM, the delegate for processing CMYK PDFs uses the pamcmyk32 device. Some suggest changing that to pngalpha but that forces an unwanted change to the RGB color space. Some suggest converting first to PNG then back to CMYK but that results in color data loss.

Using Ghostscript directly none of the device options for TIFF have any options for transparency. After digging around for a while I found an old post reply from a dev at Artifex (KenS) stating that “As for TIFF, there is no support in GS for making the unmarked areas transparent”.:
[Conversion...does not maintain transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396506/conversion-of-eps-to-pdf-or-tiff-does-not-maintain-transparency)

It was disheartening but it was from 2011 so I’m holding out hope that there is some workaround for this issue by now. I’m searching for some configuration change to Ghostscript that will enable me to set all unmarked areas to transparent, or get it to start with a page erased to transparent rather than white.

The TIFF file format supports both CMYK color space and transparency so there must be a way to get both in the same file. Any insight into how to get both inside a TIFF would be welcome at this point. Thanks for reading.

Comment: As far as I know, Ghostscript still will not process transparency in CMYK colorspace. You could use ImageMagick to convert your CMYK PDF to sRGB using -colorspace sRGB, which uses Ghostscript, before reading the PDF, then once you have done that, you can convert to tiff by adding profiles from sRGB to CMYK before outputting the TIFF. `magick -colorspace sRGB -density XX image.pdf -profile path/to/sRGB.icc -profile path/to/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc image.tiff`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fred. I'm a big fan of your scripts. I'm by no means an expert on color spaces but I work with one on this project. As I understand it, converting from CMYK to RGB and back to CMYK will result in degradation of the color data. Wouldn't that happen if I follow the process you've suggested?   -Thanks

Comment: Only slightly due to using -colorspace sRGB rather than a profile. But since your input is CMYK pdf, does it have a profile or not. If no profile, then your CMYK colors are not well defined to be reproducible on all viewing platforms. You really need to have profiles. Also is does your PDF contain a raster image? If so, then you would be better off extracting the image from the PDF using pdfimages and processing from there especially if the raster image has a built in profile. Try my command and see how much difference there is. Or post your PDF and I can try.

Comment: I just ran some color tests where where I did the conversions from CMYK -> sRGB ->CMYK. What I got were some minor drifts in individual colors as expected. I didn't think they were that substantial but my co-developer feels they are enough of a concern to try and avoid the conversion chain. It's looking like I may have to go back to the comments from @KenS and try to get Ghostscript to skip the white-fill part of the PDF conversion. Anything to do with IM or Ghostscript will have the same issues unless I can get around that.

Comment: What type of image did you use for your CMYK -> sRGB ->CMYK. Did you just use -colorspace  or did you use profiles. ImageMagick does very well with raster images and profiles. PDF CMYK files are a problem if they have transparency, due to limitations of Ghostscript.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I created a color test pattern that included multiple CMYK color combinations as well as transparency levels in Adobe Illustrator, saved it as a PDF, used GS to convert to TIFF, verified the colors held, and then did the conversions with -colorspace only. I'm still looking for a good source for the color profiles. The two sources I know are /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/*.icc and [color.org](http://www.color.org). What do you think is the "best" source for color profiles? -Thanks

Comment: Try both sources and see which ones give the best results.

Comment: I took some time and consulted with a person who actually does color analysis. I then wrote some code that would automate the comparison process after doing conversions from CMYK->RGB->CMYK. The results all had a common factor. Dark CMYK colors that didn't have a K component had a significant one after the conversion. He's an example:

cmyk(128,78,78,0) was converted to cmyk(72,0,0,78) 
cmyk(127,77,77,0) was converted to cmyk(72,0,0,77)
cmyk(159,96,96,0) was converted to cmyk(101,0,0,96) 

There is lots more data and it was similar for multiple profile files.

Comment: I neglected to add the profile files I tried:
 - ghostscript/srgb.icc 
 - ghostscript/ps_cmyk.icc 
 - GRACoL2013UNC_CRPC3.icc
 - SWOP2013C3_CRPC5.icc 
 - GRACoL2013_CRPC6.icc

(Sorry for the ugly list)

Given those results I'm really reluctant to try using the intermediate step of converting to RGBA-PNG before converting to CMYKA-TIF. The color drift, while not as noticeable to the average eye, won't fly with print quality checks.  So I'm back to looking for a way to do a conversion from the original CMYKA-PDF into CMYKA-TIF.

Comment: Ghostscript will not process CMYK with alpha properly. So you need to convert to RGBA via -colorspace sRGB before reading the PDF, then you can use profiles to convert directly to CMYKA TIF. There is no reason to explicitly save to PNG as an intermediate file.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this one @fmw42. I did some tests, as you suggested, converting directly to CMYK without writing to a file. I tried calling out the RGB color space before reading the PDF. Here's an example of one of my commands:
convert -colorspace RGB  trans-test.pdf -profile /usr/share/color/icc/ghostscript/ps_cmyk.icc -colorspace CMYK output_CMYK.tif

I see a color shift from (78.04%,0%,100%,0%) to (71.37%,10.98%,100%,0.78%)

Comment: I discovered that using "-colorspace" before a file operator "trans-test.pdf" had no effect. Looking at the documentation I see that -colorspace is a "Simple Image Processing Operator" and "they must be given after the images for which they are to operate, have been read into memory.". (https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/)

Can you give me an example of how you can specify it before reading in the PDF?  -Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some creative solutions would be needed to get around the delegate limitations -- as pointed out in the comments.

I would suggest extracting the transparency to an intermediate mask, and reapply it after enabling the CMYKA data channels.

```sh
# Create transparent mask (we don't care about colorspace, just grab the alpha channel values)
convert -depth 8 -colorspace sRGB trans-test.pdf -alpha Extract mask.png
# Apply mask _after_ enabling alpha channel
convert \( \
        -depth 8 \
        -colorspace CMYK \
        trans-test.pdf \
        -alpha Activate \
    \) \
    mask.png -compose CopyAlpha -composite output.tif
```

The `-alpha Activate` turn on the alpha channel, but there's no data so everything is transparent. Following `mask.png -compose CopyAlpha -composite` populates the alpha channel with the values extracted from the previous operation.

[image: Example output with CMYKA]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did look into trying something like this. I ran in to the issue of the initial conversion still placing white behind the partially transparent areas.  See [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xr3537s8fgbt8me/xbPGa_markup.png?dl=0). The area in yellow now is a gray rather than transparent. The area in red is the real issue. Even if the alpha extract/replace works perfectly, that area still has white behind it making it "milky" rather than  translucent. Did I miss something on the transparent area turning grey?  -Thanks

Comment: The gray is the background of OSX's Preview.app, and the dotted line represents the image edge. It's an example of the image as S.O. doesn't support `tif` images - Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Up until now I'd been relying quite heavily on Gimp to view my images because it made it very clear what areas are transparent and has good analysis tools. After @fmw42 posts I went back and checked the image produced by your solution in Adobe Illustrator (AI) and see that areas that were shown as white in Gimp, including the area I highlighted in red, are shown as transparent in AI.  There is some color-space alteration and I'm still looking into that. I'm down to questioning even the image viewer tools at this point. More soon. -Thanks

Comment: Here are two limitations I learned about GIMP in my recent testing: 1) GIMP has trouble with CMYK tif files with transparency. If the file has a transparent background it will inscribe the colored areas in a background of white. The areas in the inscribed area that were also transparent will become black. So far the only way I've been able to verify this is to open the file in Adobe Illustrator to cross check.  2) For CMYK files, GIMP converts cmyk(255,255,255,0) and cmyk(255, 255, 255, 255) to (0,0,0,255). You'll see this when you use the pointer/sample tool to view values a specific pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I compared my solution to that of emcconville. His approach should be a good one, but my profile solution seems to match colors better in saved tif files displayed in Mac OSX Sierra Preview, GraphicConverter and Photoshop. Commands below are unix syntax in IM 7.0.7.37 Q16 HDRI and LIBTIFF Version 4.0.9 Ghostscript 9.23. You can see your versions from `magick -list format`.

Input:
[trans-test.pdf](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/pdf2tif/trans-test.pdf)

My solution:

```
magick -depth 8 -colorspace sRGB trans-test.pdf \
-profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/sRGB.icc \
-profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc \
trans-test_profile.tif
```

[trans-test_profile.tif](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/pdf2tif/trans-test_profile.tif)

emcconville's solution:

```
magick -depth 8 -colorspace sRGB trans-test.pdf -alpha Extract mask.png

magick \( -depth 8 -colorspace CMYK trans-test.pdf \) \
mask.png -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite \
trans-test_mask.tif
```

[trans-test_mask.tif](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/pdf2tif/trans-test_mask.tif)

Note that -compose copyOpacity or copyAlpha generally requires -alpha off. Therefore, I do not see any reason to add -alpha activate.

Here are my delegates:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-37 Q16 x86_64 2018-05-30 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The links to your tif outputs seem to be broken. I tried your solution and the result I got was CMYK but the transparency data is still shown as white. Also there black bars added

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The links to your tif outputs seem to be broken. I tried your solution. The result I got was CMYK but the transparency data is still shown as white. Also there's a black bar added next to the green area. See [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nkzdtjei9032g1/trans-test_profile.tif?dl=0) Oddly, The bar is only black when viewed on in Linux with Gimp. Viewed in Windows to post this it shows as white. Looking at the new black area in Gimp it has the same alpha value as the white area which should be transparent. Not sure why it gets rendered differently. I'll study that. -Thx

Comment: Sorry about the broken links. I have fixed them, now. Please note that some viewers do not know how to display CMYK(A) properly without a profile. I am not sure if this is the issue. They display as described above on my Mac OSX Sierra in Safari, also. Windows syntax is different. Remove the \ for before \( ... \), change end of line \ to ^.  There may also be issues with IM versions and libtif. In IM 6, the mask needs to be negated. My results do not show that black bar.

Comment: See the edits to my answer above with some information about my system configuration and the fixed links.

Comment: Oddly GIMP 2.8 on my Mac displays my solution with the black bar you noted, but not the other solution. Also the colors are all nearly the same. But they display as I mentioned fine in the tools that I listed. So I have to assume it is a GIMP issue.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works as expected. For me, the black-bar/border issue seems to resolve itself when increasing the density past 200.

Comment: Up until now I'd been relying quite heavily on Gimp to view my images because it made it very clear what areas are transparent and has good analysis tools. After your post I went back and checked the image produced by your solution in Adobe Illustrator (AI) and it shows that it's actualy transparent in the areas where GIMP shows it as white. There is some color-space alteration and I'm still looking into that. I'm down to questioning even the image viewer tools at this point. More soon. -Thanks

Comment: Also, @emcconville and fmw42, where do you get your color profile files? I was able to google around and find copies of sRGB.icc and  USWebCoatedSWOP.icc but I'd like to use the same source as you if possible. Are you getting them from here: http://www.color.org ? If so, which versions? -Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure where I got all my profiles, but many did come from color.org. That seems to be a reliable place to get them. I am not sure which sRGB profile I am using as it got renamed, but probably v2. Most viewers will respect a profile and that typically makes the viewing consistent. When loading in Photoshop, it often asks if you want to use the imbedded profile or some other. I am not sure what GIMP does by default. Perhaps it removes the profile or uses some other.